# Как выводить/изменять множество вкладок на сайте

Tags: php, javascript, html

Во время создания сайта возник вопрос, страницы сайта состоят из множества вкладок с тестами(прим. фото), как организовать управление ими без `CMS`? Сейчас приходится добавлять каждую новую вручную(заполнять название и путь), но хочется автоматизировать процесс. В этом и вопрос, где хранить их названия и местоположение и как выводить их на страницу не редактируя постоянно исходный код? Как их можно потом удалять? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы не хотите использовать готовую CMS, то тогда отчасти придется писать ее функционал самостоятельно. Если кратко, в базе данных потребуются таблицы с содержимым и адресами страниц. Также нужна хотя бы минималистичная административная панель, где вы будете управлять страницами. Для удаления пишется отдельная функция/метод, который удаляет запрашиваемую страницы через GET-запрос или обращение к AJAX.

Comment: Проблемы CMS в том, что их крайне проблематично поставить на готовый сайт, нужно или много знаний(коими пока не блистаю), или сразу писать на каком-то движке, который маловероятно, что будет поддерживать такой функционал в дизайне и точной настройке

Comment: Тогда в вашем случае потребуется написать собственный минималистичный движок, но это более сложная задача, чем установить популярную CMS. Попробуйте все же перевести сайт на одну из бесплатных CMS. По хорошему, если на сайте нет сложного функционала, то потребуется настроить шаблоны и перевести всю информацию в базу.

Comment: согласен. но так же можно написать простенькое хранилище этих разделов с тестами в одном или нескольких файлах. в любом случае. нужны относительно хорошие знания php как минимум.